# 2 Very similar queries return different number of result (one is null)

Tags: mysql-5.5, full-text-search

I want to find businesses near a point that contain a word that start with sea

lat=-6.185068&long=106.773121&keyword=sea&distance=5000&startfrom=0&howmany=20&prominent=5

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.185-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.773-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98839228980165) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  TB.Latitude >-6.2317830813328 AND TB.Latitude < -6.1382169186672
   AND TB.Longitude >106.72621691867 AND TB.Longitude <106.81978308133
  AND MATCH (TA.FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('sea*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND TA.Prominent >5
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 20
```

I got these result:

```
rasane__-6.18_106.77    -6.1826789706189    106.774375525435    299.434343596808
seafood-bangka---jakarta__-6.18_106.77  -6.18410749805068   106.767679452896    596.253784623613
seafood-sari-laut__-6.19_106.78     -6.18661497692636   106.7816047167  967.65389600759
rasane-seafood-restaurant__-6.18_106.76     -6.18244550827744   106.763621456218    1074.56073316741
pecel-lele-lela__-6.19_106.78   -6.18836286783996   106.782370851856    1100.91660371997
bintang-laut-seafood__-6.18_106.77  -6.17782494896301   106.766016483307    1109.75958732106
d'cost-itc-permata-hijau__-6.19_106.77  -6.19494204046746   106.770504692048    1138.95344788546
masterpiece---car-leather-seat-and-interior__-6.18...   -6.18373417378944   106.783719062805    1192.82955595065
seafood-makasar__-6.18_106.78   -6.17684    106.780666  1241.07275264282
hongkong-jumbo-seafood-restaurant__-6.20_106.77     -6.19668602280699   106.771334150698    1311.89593536338
plg-(pecel-lele-greenville)__-6.17_106.78   -6.17354759635866   106.7768121112  1340.84148631128
makassar__-6.18_106.78  -6.17990504916375   106.784087464957    1349.76048368113
makassar-seafood__-6.20_106.77  -6.19642790400783   106.768355369568    1370.00078243887
pelangi-seafood__-6.17_106.78   -6.1733876537374    106.777818202972    1396.23099579268
sea-food-sari-laut-kemanggisan__-6.19_106.79    -6.188395   106.7853    1410.61411729396
seafood-toni-k__-6.19_106.79    -6.188435   106.785291  1410.85254243932
seafood-sari-laut-tony-koeswoyo__-6.19_106.79   -6.188445   106.785417  1424.55989808634
makassar-seafood-restaurant__-6.18_106.78   -6.177669   106.783744  1439.9871117091
sea-food-38-kebon-jeruk__-6.20_106.77   -6.19710303086272   106.767730987066    1465.8643124913
seafood-38-(lap.-bola)__-6.20_106.77    -6.197078   106.767655  1466.67274960557
```

Now I run the similar query based on something slightly different
lat=-6.185564&long=106.775518&keyword=Sea&distance=5000&startfrom=0&howmany=20&prominent=5
Notice that the lat and long differs only a little bit

The query doesn't change much

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326*SQRT(pow(-6.186-TB.Latitude,2)+pow(106.776-TB.Longitude,2)*0.98838855059148) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  join tableauxiliary as TA on TA.BusinessID=TB.ID
WHERE
  TB.Latitude >-6.2327830813328 AND TB.Latitude < -6.1392169186672
   AND TB.Longitude >106.72921691867 AND TB.Longitude <106.82278308133
  AND MATCH (TA.FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('Sea*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND TA.Prominent >5
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 20
```

This one returns empty

I put the 2 queries side by side. Obviously many of the result are within the rectangle.

How come?

Can anyone spot some obvious bugs in these? Maybe I did something wrong in SQL command

Comment: [This](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22343) bug report (which turned out not to report a bug, but a (for me at least) cryptic feature) can be useful for you.  You write sea* here and Sea* there.  I found the link by searching for case sensitivity in full text search.

Comment: Please turn that into an answer. That is PRECISELY the problem.

Comment: However TA.FullTextSearch is only one column and the collation is UTF8. So I wonder why it's still case sensitive?

Comment: another problem is the collation. It's utf8bin rather than utfcollation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write sea* here and Sea* there.  [This](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22343) bug report (which turned out not to report a bug, but a (for me at least) cryptic feature) can be useful for you. (I found the link by searching for case sensitivity in full text search.)